# How to reverse "This is friday" to "friday is this" in vb.net in Easiest Way

Tags: vb.net

'How to reverse "This is Friday" to "Friday is this"  in vb.net in Easiest Way

```
Dim str As String = txtremarks.Text
        Dim arr As New List(Of Char)
        arr.AddRange(str.ToCharArray)
        arr.Reverse()
        Dim a As String = ""

        For Each l As Char In arr
            a &= l

        Next
```

' I saw on a few forums that to use SPLIT function. Please help

Comment: `Dim revString As String = String.Join(" ", "This is friday".Split(" ").Reverse())`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use split.  You can also use join and the reverse method:

```
Dim test = "This is Friday"
Dim reversetest = String.Join(" ", test.Split().Reverse)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First you'll want to split your sentence into individual words. This is where you'd use the [String.Split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. Once you have an array containing your individual words, you can reverse that array. Perhaps using [Linq's Enumerable.Reverse extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
3. Finally, you can put the words back together into a string. The [String.Join method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allows you to join the elements of a string array back into a single string.

I'm not a VB programmer, but something like this should work:

```
Dim str As String = "this is friday"
Dim split As String() = str.Split(" ")
Dim result as String = String.Join(" ", split.Reverse())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it in 1 line:

```
Dim reverse As String = "This is friday".Split().Reverse().Aggregate(Function(left, right) String.Join(" ", left, right))
```

Do note that this has a horrible performance overhead.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can Split your String via " " (space) and insert results into array. 
Next, read array from the end to start. 
Good luck!

Comment: I cannot comment. I get a message, I need to have mroe than 50 rep. You don't help me ...

Comment: You get reputation through providing good answers.  You do not help yourself by providing bad answers, such as this one.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
 Dim txt As String = "This is friday"
 Dim txtarray() As String = Split(txt.Trim(), " ")
 Dim result As String = ""
 For x = txtarray.GetUpperBound(0) To 0 Step -1
     result += txtarray(x) & " "
 Next x
 MsgBox(result.Trim())
```

Comment: Downvoted because this code obscures the intent.  Take a look at @tinstaafl's answer for an example of code that makes its intent very clear.